# Complex initialization in class in c++ type 'complex<double>' does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++, class, oop, complex-numbers

Hi I currently tried to initialize a complex number within a class

```
class complex_class{

    public:

        complex<double> mycomplex;

        complex_class(double real, double img){

            //mycomplex(real, img);
            mycomplex.real(real);
            mycomplex.imag(img);

        }

};
```

when I tried to assign some values directly, an error message appeared

error: type 'complex' does not provide a call operator
            mycomplex(real, img);

it works just only with functions real and imag

So I would like to ask u guys what I did so wrong and what I didn't understood.

thanks for reading and helping

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve] .  We need to see what you are compiling.

Comment: Constructors for members can only be called in the initializer list of the containing constructor, not in the function body.

Answer (score 2):

Member variables are constructed and initialized before the constructor body is called.

If you want to initialize a member variable as part of the object initialization, you need to do it before the constructor body is called, and for that you need to use a *constructor initializer list*.

Something like

```
complex_class(double real, double img)
    : mycomplex(real, img)   // Initialize the mycomplex object through its constructor
{
    // Empty, as mycomplex already is initialized
}
```